# How to reload page/router in handleSubmit method after submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a login form.

What I need to do is to get it to reload the page / route after the user clicks the submit button.

The reason for this is that after the submit button is clicked some changes are needed on the nav component which is not this one.

You can see that I use ***sessionStorage.setItem('something', 'somevalue');*** which then the nav component reads and makes some changes.

At the moment to get to see the changes I need to reload the browser.

Here is the code:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };

    this.onUsernameChange = this.onUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this);
  }

  onUsernameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
  }

  onPasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    sessionStorage.setItem('something', 'somevalue');
    // reload the page here or re-router to current page/router

  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
          <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" value={this.username} onChange={this.onUsernameChange} />
            <input type="password" value={this.password} onChange={this.onPasswordChange} />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good idea would be to use `onEnter` callbacks in your routes or subscribe to changes on `sessionStore` (is that a `redux` store?) to check for updates, and allow that information to propagate down through the app.

To answer your question about navigation, however, you can use either:

`location.reload()` - `location` is a standard JavaScript (browser) object

or inject React Router's `router` using the provided `withRouter` component enhancer.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

...

export default withRouter(Login);
```

`router` will be available in `props` - you can use it like

```
const { router } = this.props
router.push('/some/route')
```

this will trigger a view change **without reloading the window** (which is why I was suggesting making sure that you can update your component's knowledge about the session without reloading the page)

**edit** - by the way `event` is undefined in `handleSubmit`

Comment: wow thanks for this. browserHistory.push is the same as router.push ?

Comment: I honestly don't know... but if I had to hazard a guess, I'd say that React Router is using `HistoryInterface#push(...)` (based on whatever history provider you give to React Router's `Provider`) behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to propose a more drastic (and maybe more scalable) solution. It sounds like you want to access the state of your `<Login />` component within at least one other, sibling or parent, component.

One method for doing this would be to use a [state management solution like Redux](http://redux.js.org/). A solution using Redux would be beyond the scope of a solution here, but definitely look into it as it might be the optimal solution.

That said, there's another way we can tackle this - by maintaining state in  a parent component and passing the `username` and `password` state as props to the various components that need them.

To do this we'll create a parent component `<App />` which will contain 2 child components:

- `<Login />`
- `<Nav />`

The login component will be the form you already have, with some minor changes. Instead of maintaining it's own state, it will receive the `handleSubmit` function as a prop from it's parent.

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" name="username" />
          <input type="password" name="password" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You'll notice the form is using `this.props.handleSubmit` for the `onSubmit` event. We'll get to this below.

We'll also create a `<Nav />` component to show the user's name, which will receive a `username` prop.

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        Nav
        <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
          {this.props.username && `Welcome ${this.props.username}`}
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Again, you'll notice we're using `this.props.username` to display the user's name. We'll get to this below.

Finally, we'll create our parent component `<App />` where all the magic happens.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      username: event.target.elements.username.value,
      password: event.target.elements.password.value
    });

    // Do your session storage here if needed
    // sessionStorage.setItem('something', 'somevalue');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav username={this.state.username} />
        <Login
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

That's a lot to take in at first glance. In short, this component is maintaining the state, and passing a `handleSubmit` function to the `<Login />` component. When the login form is submitted, the username and password are stored in state in the this `<App /> component instead of being confined to the``component. This allows us to pass the`username`and`password`down as props to any other child components. Like the`` component.

You'll remember in the `<Nav />` component we used `this.props.username`. When the login form is submitted, it updates the state in the `<App />` component which then passes the `username` to the `<Nav />` component for use.

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/YQeVax?editors=1010) showing the app in action.

Comment: +1 - that's a common design pattern called Lifting State Up: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html